# Batch delete throws QueryCollectorSignal exception?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jooq

When I try to do a batch delete, nothing happens. I stepped into the debugger, and see that BatchCRUD::executeAction calls UpdatableRecord::delete, and down in the callstack, UpdatableRecordImpl::checkIfChanged calls fetchOne() which throws a QueryCollectorSignal. The sql executed works fine in PGAdmin (postgres), so I'm wondering what's going on here? How do I do a proper batch delete?

Comment: For the record, this question was also posted on the jOOQ user group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jooq-user/s5LRaaZDuAQ/Icip48XoCAAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When does this happen:

1. you have turned on the executeWithOptimisticLocking setting
2. this particular table doesn't have any timestamp or version column

#### Why does this happen?

`batchStore()`, `batchDelete()` and similar calls execute the respective `store()`, `delete()` etc. calls on each individual `UpdatableRecord`, but with an `ExecuteListener` that aborts execution (via this `QueryCollectorSignal` exception) and just collects the SQL query that would have been executed. It then batches these SQL queries, rather than executing them individually. The ExecuteListener is, unfortunately, also applied to the SELECT query that is needed for optimistic locking.

The safest solution would probably be to just turn off optimistic locking before we provide a fix. I've registered an issue for this:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5383

Comment: Thanks again Lukas!